# Ocultar y mostrar con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo una duda en cuanto a ocultar y mostrar ciertas opciones de una subcategoría, por ejemplo tengo categoría de ropa y su subcategoría tendrá un `id="ropa"` en los cuales estarán calcetines, camisetas etc. y tendré otras categorías con sus respectivas subcategorias.

Abajo les muestro el código que estoy tratando de usar pero no funciona no entiendo porque (Soy novato en javascript).

```js
function mostrar(){
var x = document.getElementsByName("Videojuegos y diversión");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'true';
}
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="try.html">
<select name="CATEGORIA" id="CATEGORIA" onchange="mostrar()" required>
   <option selected value="2"> Elige una opción </option>
       <option value="Electrónicos">Electrónicos</option>
       <option value="Videojuegos y diversión">Videojuegos y diversión</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
 
<select name="SUBCATEGORIA" id="SUBCATEGORIA" required>
<option selected value=""> Elige una opción </option>
   <option value="Accesorios videojuegos" style='display:none;' id="Videojuegos y diversión" >Accesorios videojuegos</option>
   <option value="Consolas" style='display:none;' style='display:none;' id="Videojuegos y diversión" >Consolas</option>
   <option value="Deportes y actividades al aire libre" style='display:none;' id="Videojuegos y diversión">Deportes y actividades al aire libre</option>
   <option value="Videojuegos" style='display:none;' id="Videojuegos y diversión">Videojuegos</option>
   <option value="Accesorios videojuegos" style='display:none;' id="Electrónicos" >TV</option>
   <option value="Accesorios videojuegos" style='display:none;' id="Electrónicos" >Eqipo de sonido</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
 
<input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Comment: No deberías tener **jamás** más de un elemento con el mismo `id`. Deberían ser únicos. Quizás podrías reescribir el HTML usando `class` para marcar elementos dentro de una misma categoría: `<option value="..." class="videojuegosdiversion" ...>`. Y luego, obtendrías todos los elementos de una clase con `.getElementsByClassName()`.

Answer (score 1):

Si de verdad necesitas llamar los selects de **SUBCATEGORIA** con id, esta es una solución:

```js
function cambiar() {
 var x = document.getElementById("SUBCATEGORIA");
 var vacio = new Option("Elige una opción","");
 x.options[x.options.length] = vacio;
 x.selectedIndex = vacio;
}
function mostrar(){
 var categoria = document.getElementById("CATEGORIA").value;
 var x = document.getElementById("SUBCATEGORIA"); 
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (x.options[i].id == categoria){
      x.options[i].style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      x.options[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
 }
 if (categoria == 2 || categoria == null) {
  var vacio = new Option("Elige una opción","");
  x.options[x.options.length] = vacio;
  x.selectedIndex = vacio;
 }
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="try.html">
<select name="CATEGORIA" id="CATEGORIA" onchange="cambiar()" onClick="mostrar()" required>
   <option selected value="2"> Elige una opción </option>
       <option value="Electrónicos">Electrónicos</option>
       <option value="Videojuegos y diversión">Videojuegos y diversión</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
 
<select name="SUBCATEGORIA" id="SUBCATEGORIA" required>
<option selected value=""> Elige una opción </option>
   <option value="Accesorios videojuegos" style='display:none;' id="Videojuegos y diversión" >Accesorios videojuegos</option>
   <option value="Consolas" style='display:none;' style='display:none;' id="Videojuegos y diversión" >Consolas</option>
   <option value="Deportes y actividades al aire libre" style='display:none;' id="Videojuegos y diversión">Deportes y actividades al aire libre</option>
   <option value="Videojuegos" style='display:none;' id="Videojuegos y diversión">Videojuegos</option>
   <option value="Accesorios videojuegos" style='display:none;' id="Electrónicos" >TV</option>
   <option value="Accesorios videojuegos" style='display:none;' id="Electrónicos" >Eqipo de sonido</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
 
<input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Comment: Es una **mala práctica** dar el mismo id a varios elementos, como lo dice el mismo nombre, un id es algo **único**. JS y jQuery funcionan mal, podrían dar resultados inesperados cuando usamos el mismo id para más de un elemento.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar jquery para eso. con .hide y .show.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: la solución requerida es con javascript, no jquery